# Позиционирование слайдов Swiper

Tags: javascript, html, css

Долго уже ломаю как установить слайды таким образом как на картинке, каждая картинка - это 1 слайд.

Делаю :

```
    slidesPerView: 6,
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    slidesPerGroup: 6,
```

Но они тогда все в линию становятся, нужно как-будто `flex-wrap`. в API не могу найти нужного параметра. у контейнера фиксированная ширина.

Если я задам `slider-wrapper` `flex-wrap:wrap`, то все ломается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

в настройках слайдера надо добавить следующее свойство:

```
 slidesPerView: 3,
  grid: {
    rows: 2,
  },
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Не внимательно читаете документацию к swiper, там описан метод, который позиционирует слайды в две строки, в 6 версии это было SlidesPerColumn, в 7-й это уже rows в группе свойств grid. Ответ вам верный дали, я знаю где такой слайдер вы верстаете)